# WebGL; Instanced rendering - setting up divisors

Tags: buffer, webgl, instance

I'm trying to draw a lot of cubes in webgl using instanced rendering (`ANGLE_instanced_arrays`).

However I can't seem to wrap my head around how to setup the divisors. I have the following buffers;

36 vertices (6 faces made from 2 triangles using 3 vertices each).
6 colors per cube (1 for each face).
1 translate per cube.

To reuse the vertices for each cube; I've set it's divisor to 0.
For color I've set the divisor to 2 (i.e. use same color for two triangles - a face)).
For translate I've set the divisor to 12 (i.e. same translate for 6 faces * 2 triangles per face).

For rendering I'm calling

`ext_angle.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 36, num_cubes);`

This however does not seem to render my cubes.

Using translate divisor 1 does but the colors are way off then, with cubes being a single solid color.

I'm thinking it's because my instances are now the full cube, but if I limit the `count` (i.e. vertices per instance), I do not seem to get all the way through the vertices buffer, effectively I'm just rendering one triangle per cube then.

How would I go about rendering a lot of cubes like this; with varying colored faces?

Comment: Worth adding; each cube has uniquely colored faces.

Comment: Try to set translate divisor to 1 so it changes once per instance (your instance is cube, not face).

Comment: @mlkn: Then how will I change the colors uniquely for each face?

Comment: I think it would be best to make color non instanced attribute.

Comment: @mkln, but then all the cubes would have the same face colors right? - aka. a cubes face colors wouldn't be unique?

Comment: For the sake of the question; consider that ALL faces have to be distinct colors generates at random (globally unique, NOT just cube unique).

Comment: Face colors will be unique but you have to make not indexed drawing this way.

Comment: If you want unique colors per face per cube (as in 3 cubes = 18 colors) then you'd still need one color per vertex per instance. `ANGLE_instanced_arrays` only lets you repeat data in an attribute per instance, not per vertex. 0 = never repeat, just do the normal thing. 1 = repeat the same data for the entire instance (ie, repeat for the entire cube), 2 = repeat for 2 instances (ie, 2 cubes). There's no way to repeat per face. Yet another reason why using textures *might* be better (although I have no idea about speed)

Comment: @mlkn 'make not indexed drawing'? - I'm not sure I follow? - abandon instanced based rendering all together?

Comment: @gman couldn't my instances just be triangles or faces instead of cubes then? - I'm a bit scared off by the idea of using texture memory; I'm new to webgl.

Comment: Just to confirm; I do want unique colors per face per cube.

Comment: Could I make my instances faces, and then just provide 1 color per face, and use the same translate for 6 faces?

Comment: @gman: Not primCount = numCubes and count = 6?

Comment: But this doesn't sound efficient since transforms will be passed 6x times. (Answering previous question: Indexed drawing is technique of reusing vertices which are shared by multiple faces).

Comment: @mlkn is indexed drawing equivalent to using drawElements? - Because I was using that, but couldn't apply it with instancing.

Comment: @Skeen Yes it is it.

Comment: @mkln: Can you explain how I'd reuse my 36 (or 24 with indexing) cube vertices, while using a unique translate and 6 unique colors per cube? - Because when I tried it I always ended up having to use either uniforms or duplicating vertex data.

Comment: @Skeen I am saying that indexing is **not** applicable in your case. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: Just to cleanup confusion; I'm NOT attempting indexed drawing, but rather instanced drawing. I apologize for misunderstanding you.

Comment: @Skeen speaking of your case I suggest making color per vertex attribute and then keep cubes as instances with instanced attribute position with divisor 1.

Comment: @mlkn: How can I provide per-vertex attributes when rendering using instancing? - I was under the impression that you couldn't mix (I.e. that when using instancing all your attributes would be instanced).

Comment: @Skeen Just as you do with positions (this way you will have cubes with different colored faces but each cube will be colored same way)

Comment: @mlkn: Every cube needs to have faces, those colors are different from any color which is used by any other faces for any other cubes.

Comment: @Skeen Then having different color for each face and instanced attribute with cube-Id for example you could compute it in vertex shader.

Comment: @mlkn: It feels like this thing is going towards the texture approach, i.e. provide cube and vertex ids' and lookup in a texture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instancing works like this:

Eventually you are going to call

```
ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(mode, first, numVertices, numInstances);
```

So let's say you're drawing instances of a cube. One cube has 36 vertices (6 per face * 6 faces). So

```
numVertices = 36
```

And lets say you want to draw 100 cubes so

```
numInstances = 100
```

Let's say you have a vertex shader like this

Let's say you have the following shader

```
attribute vec4 position;

uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
```

If you did nothing else and just called

```
var mode = gl.TRIANGLES;
var first = 0;
var numVertices = 36
var numInstances = 100

ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(mode, first, numVertices, numInstances);
```

It would just draw the same cube in the same exact place 100 times

Next up you want to give each cube a different translation so you update your shader to this

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 translation;

uniform mat4 matrix;

void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * (position + vec4(translation, 0));
}
```

You now make a buffer and put one translation per cube then you setup the attribute like normal

```
gl.vertexAttribPointer(translationLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0)
```

But you also set a divisor

```
ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(translationLocation, 1);
```

That 1 says '*only advance to the next value in the translation buffer once per instance*'

Now you want have a different color per face per cube and you only want one color per face in the data (you don't want to repeat colors). **There is no setting that would to that**  Since your `numVertices = 36` you can only choose to advance every vertex (divisor = 0) or once every multiple of 36 vertices (ie, numVertices).

So you say, what if instance faces instead of cubes? Well now you've got the opposite problem. Put one color per face. `numVertices = 6`, `numInstances = 600` (100 cubes * 6 faces per cube). You set color's divisor to 1 to advance the color once per face. You can set translation divisor to 6 to advance the translation only once every 6 faces (every 6 instances). But now you no longer have a cube you only have a single face. In other words you're going to draw 600 faces all facing the same way, every 6 of them translated to the same spot.

To get a cube back you'd have to add something to orient the face instances in 6 direction.

Ok, you fill a buffer with 6 orientations. That won't work. You can't set divisor to anything that will use those 6 orientations advance only once every face but then resetting after 6 faces for the next cube. There's only 1 divisor setting. Setting it to 6 to repeat per face or 36 to repeat per cube but you want advance per face **and** reset back per cube. No such option exists.

What you can do is draw it with 6 draw calls, one per face direction. In other words you're going to draw all the left faces, then all the right faces, the all the top faces, etc...

To do that we make just 1 face, 1 translation per cube, 1 color per face per cube. We set the divisor on the translation and the color to 1.

Then we draw 6 times, one for each face direction. The difference between each draw is we pass in an orientation for the face and we change the attribute offset for the color attribute and set it's stride to 6 * 4 floats (6 * 4 * 4).

```js
var vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 translation;
attribute vec4 color;

uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 localMatrix;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  vec4 localPosition = localMatrix * position + vec4(translation, 0);
  gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * localPosition;
  v_color = color;
}
`;

var fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
`;

var m4 = twgl.m4;
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var ext = gl.getExtension("ANGLE_instanced_arrays");
if (!ext) {
  alert("need ANGLE_instanced_arrays");
}
var program = twgl.createProgramFromSources(gl, [vs, fs]);

var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
var translationLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "translation");
var colorLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "color");

var localMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "localMatrix");
var viewProjectionMatrixLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(
    program, 
    "viewProjectionMatrix");

function r(min, max) {
  if (max === undefined) {
    max = min;
    min = 0;
  }
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

function rp() {
  return r(-20, 20);
}

// make translations and colors, colors are separated by face
var numCubes = 1000;
var colors = [];
var translations = [];

for (var cube = 0; cube < numCubes; ++cube) {
  translations.push(rp(), rp(), rp());

  // pick a random color;
  var color = [r(1), r(1), r(1), 1];

  // now pick 4 similar colors for the faces of the cube
  // that way we can tell if the colors are correctly assigned
  // to each cube's faces.
  var channel = r(3) | 0;  // pick a channel 0 - 2 to randomly modify
  for (var face = 0; face < 6; ++face) {
    color[channel] = r(.7, 1);
    colors.push.apply(colors, color);
  }
}

var buffers = twgl.createBuffersFromArrays(gl, {
  position: [  // one face
    -1, -1, -1,
    -1,  1, -1,
     1, -1, -1,
     1, -1, -1,
    -1,  1, -1,
     1,  1, -1,
  ],
  color: colors, 
  translation: translations,
});

var faceMatrices = [
  m4.identity(),
  m4.rotationX(Math.PI /  2),
  m4.rotationX(Math.PI / -2),
  m4.rotationY(Math.PI /  2),
  m4.rotationY(Math.PI / -2),
  m4.rotationY(Math.PI),
];

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;

  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.position);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.translation);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(translationLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(translationLocation, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers.color);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(colorLocation);
  
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(positionLocation, 0);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(translationLocation, 1);
  ext.vertexAttribDivisorANGLE(colorLocation, 1);

  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  var fov = 60;
  var aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  var projection = m4.perspective(fov * Math.PI / 180, aspect, 0.5, 100);
  
  var radius = 30;
  var eye = [
    Math.cos(time) * radius, 
    Math.sin(time * 0.3) * radius, 
    Math.sin(time) * radius,
  ];
  var target = [0, 0, 0];
  var up = [0, 1, 0];

  var camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  var view = m4.inverse(camera);
  var viewProjection = m4.multiply(projection, view); 
  
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(viewProjectionMatrixLocation, false, viewProjection);

  // 6 faces * 4 floats per color * 4 bytes per float
  var stride = 6 * 4 * 4;  
  var numVertices = 6; 
  faceMatrices.forEach(function(faceMatrix, ndx) {
    var offset = ndx * 4 * 4;  // 4 floats per color * 4 floats
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(
       colorLocation, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, stride, offset);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(localMatrixLocation, false, faceMatrix);
    ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices, numCubes);
  });
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Could it be solved by using 6 calls to `ext.drawArraysInstancedANGLE`? - i.e. once per face.

Comment: Alternatively, how could I repeat color data to achieve what I want? - It'd still be better than what I've currently got working, namely duplication of all colors, verticies, translates and indices.

Comment: When duplicating the color, I have the problem that, with divisor 1, I'll just just 1 color for the entire cube, while with divisor 0 will just use the first 36 colors in the buffer for each cube.

Comment: Is my only option really to use an uninstanced attribute with vertex ids, and then use these to lookup into some texture? - I'd really like to avoid that.

Comment: If I repeat my colors so I have one per vertex, how do I apply then while using instancing?

Comment: I guess you can do with 6 draw calls